# How to change the color of AVPlayerViewController buttons background color

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

I am using the `AVPlayerViewController` to play video. To change the background color of buttons' controls background view as highlighted in below screenshot:-

[image]

When I tried to change the color as:-

```
self.contentOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
```

then the whole view's color get changes as below:-

[image]

How to change the color of top and bottom controls' background view.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot. `AVPlayerViewController` isn't designed for customisation. You should use `AVPlayerLayer` to customise it.

Comment: @Szu, can we always show AVPlayer controls?